# how to install Commerce Server 2007 Staging (grayed out on mine and my collegue's box)?

Tags: staging, microsoft-commerce-server

I need to use CS Staging API to do some tests with a **remote** server.
However, the Staging option is grayed out for me and my colleague, at least 
when i try to install the MSDN version (both Enterprise and Developer).
 
Any idea how can I at least use the Staging API with the remote server?
(I do not care whether I've got a local server or not)

Thanks in advance
Greg

Answer (score 0):

**You are trying to install on an unsupported OS**

You cannot *officially* install CSS on the following OS':

- Windows XP
- Windows 7
- Windows Vista

*Having said this, the Greg has got CSS working on Windows 7 by manually copying the binaries (see comments below).  Obviously, this is not supported or endorsed by Microsoft.*

**You are missing CSS pre-requisite software**

For example, classic ASP is one of the pre-requisites.  Make sure you follow
the (long) instructions in the [CS 2007 Install Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=46&SrcFamilyId=3EF4DC34-6BEC-473B-A1E4-CA3B6C5F967F&SrcDisplayLang=en&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2f3%2fa%2f4%2f3a46267f-9640-4623-86a1-c63bbfea9e1d%2fCS07InstallGuide.doc), you should be OK.  You can also review a [list of components CSS depends upon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219219%28v=cs.70%29.aspx#CSS_System_Dependent_Components).

Comment: I sometimes ask my questions too early:) Indeed, I tried to install it on an unsupported system (win7). However, brute-force copying and registering of dlls has worked for me and now I can easily connect to the remote commerce server.

Comment: Awww.  Don't I get an accepted answer for "not trying to install on an unsupported OS"?  Actually, I'll update with specific OS'.  Glad to hear that you are up and running.

Comment: hmm. the question was - how to get it to work. if you want an accepted badly, though, I can do it for you, no prob.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I read it as, "how do we get this un-grayed out".  No, I thought I had answered but as I have not, leave it.  You should put up your own answer detailing the manual copy you did.